# Using default software to open by name of file and not extension

Tags: windows, file-extension, microsoft-file-explorer

As the title mentions, is it possible to configure windows, so if lets say a file is called "exampleTest" without extension, I can configure windows so all *Test are open using, lets say VS code (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code) for example?
Thanks in advance!
ps. In any case it helps, I am trying to do this in windows 10

I couldnt find a way to configure this, I found for extensionless files (the ones I want to identify by name do not have extensions) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/13653/how-to-set-the-default-program-for-opening-files-without-an-extension-in-windows) 
my ideal behavior would be:
extensionless file? ->(yes)->its name finish by 'Test' |->(yes)-> open it in VS code
|-> (no)-> open it with notepad ++